# Hated with the Legion early in the game - Do I have to restart?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

Entered Nipton, met Vulpes, heard his speech. Decided that he had to die, so had Dynamite and the Cowboy Repeater make quick business of them.

Now I'm Level 6 and vilified with Caesar's Legion, which means that I get randomly stalked by Legion Assassins with exactly 0.00000% chance to survive. Tried planting mined or shooting at their guns, but at Level 6 it's simply not feasible to encounter them.

Do I really have to restart the game? I'm playing on the Xbox 360, so sadly no cheat console...

Comment: What kind of armaments are you carrying? Have you exploited the [shop glitch](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/9333/what-is-the-shop-glitch-in-fallout-3-new-vegas/9338#9338) to get your weaponry and armor up, to give you some chance of survival? Also, try to make it to the 188 Trading Post -- you should meet an arms dealer there with some really good stuff. Or (once you have thousands of caps) head to Silver Rush in Freeside for energy weaponry.

Comment: @John typical Level 6 stuff. I think the Service Rifle, Cowboy Repeater and .357 Revolver are my best ones, and I'm getting the red armor shield indicating I'm not getting through :/ Might try the Shop Glitch, but at the moment I can't even go to cities because I either get ambushed by Legion or by other high level enemies like Deathclaws...

Comment: Yikes! Fast track yourself to the strip, get to see Mr House. Eventually all your crimes against the Legion will be forgiven.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should be able to salvage this situation.

My suggestion? Get some backup. From Nipton, continue on to Novac ASAP and recruit Boone to watch your back - he'll go a long way to helping you survive Legion Assassins.

If you're still getting roasted every time they manage to catch you, make sure you're fighting smart: Melee weapons are better than guns for overcoming DT in the early game, and armor penetrating ammo, while not common, should be available a few rounds at a time from most vendors. Stick to the roads and watch your back, and follow the main quest as single mindedly as you can. Once you get to the Strip and meet Mr. House, you'll be able to clean your slate with the Legion and go from there.

Comment: Thanks, Boone and some better Armor eventually did the trick, but that was annoying. Restarted anyway.

Answer (score 10):

I was able to get through this encounter solo by using a bunch of meds before the battle, putting on some good armor (I think I had the space suit by this point), laying down a bunch of trip mines in the ambush's path, then alternating between my rifle (real-time) and dynamite (VATS). I had to use several stimpaks near the end, but I made it through, and I haven't seen the Legion since.

You could also try going back and finding a dead Legion NPC and wearing their armor, which may disguise you sufficiently to avoid the ambush. I didn't think of that until after I'd beat it, but it's worth a try.

Comment: +1 for the idea of rocking the Legion armor. It might just work -  certainly worth a shot. If not, the advice to load up on Chems is very good. It's easy to forget how powerful they are, or that you have them. Remember, you can always get a doctor to cure your addictions, but they can't cure death!

Answer (score 2):

If you're desperate to get past them and have a stealth boy to spare, it'll get you through the ambush without any problems

Answer (score 1):

It will help a lot if you have companion with you. Try getting ED-E in Primm. You need 3 scrap metals, 2 sensor modules and 1 scrap electronics. If you can't find the sensor module, try to make it to Novac but I think you need 30 skill in lockpick to get the evidence from Jeannie May Crawford's vault as part of quest to get Boone (One for My Baby). And really with the shop/ merchant glitch, You can buy the best gears and stimpaks your heart desires.

Better learn it because it's an easy and best cheat for console system. PC is less challenging since mods are nearly limitless.

Comment: With so much caps and ammo... I have Boone carrying " This Machine " with thousands of ammo... I got ED-E upgraded weapons and my courier has the Gobi Sniper Rifle ( thousands of hollow point 308 ammo ).... We are hunting anything thats red on the sensor