# How do you exploit the level/perk/experience glitch in "Run Goodsprings Run?"

Tags: fallout-new-vegas, cheats

OK, we've [established prior](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/9328/58) that I'm not above using certain exploits (notably the caps exploit for weapon/armor shops) when I play. This, however, is an exploit I'm not sure I would use, because it (a) really seems like it'd make the game entirely too easy and probably less fun overall (since there'd be no real level progression, therefore no motivation to keep on truckin') and (b) feels a lot like grinding. And I hate grinding.

That all said, I am curious. Over at [The Vault](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Run_Goodsprings_Run#Bugs), we have this interesting tidbit under bugs for "Run Goodsprings Run:"

> Doing the above can grant the user
>   extra free perks, before leaving the
>   area of Good Springs. You can
>   essentially level your self up to
>   level 30, and get any perks after
>   level 4 and keep them for the
>   remainder of the game. In order for
>   the glitch to work you have to level
>   up before you leave the area, where it
>   ask you to change your name, stats,
>   before you continue. Once you change
>   your stats, everything gets resetted
>   back to basic, but you keep the perks
>   you've picked before, and you get the
>   full experience points you gathered
>   aswell. It's almost like having a perk
>   every level like in Fallout 3.

The description is almost, but not quite, self-explanatory. How, exactly, does this work? I get the infinite experience glitch here. That part makes sense. What doesn't make sense is how an infinite experience glitch turns into something which is "almost like having a perk every level like in Fallout 3."

So how does that part play out?

(And again, I probably won't actually *do* this. Well, maybe in a just-for-fun/exploration playthrough, but certainly not until I've legitimately -- by my definition -- done all four factions and as much of the rest of the wastes as I can.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Essentially, the script that erases perks when you delevel as you leave Goodsprings only seems to check for level 2 perks. Ordinarily though, there's really only enough XP in the Goodsprings area to get to level 3 without a lot of tedious waiting around for Gecko respawns -  and once you've levelled up a few times, it's *a lot* of tedious waiting around.

So, while it's possible to get a free perk or two if you are, for instance [killing everyone](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/10766/killing-everyone-in-the-mojave-wasteland), it's really more effort than it's worth to go out of your way for without abusing the aforementioned infinite XP glitch. Once you do that however, basically, the way it works is you hit level 30, walk out of town, and choose to rebuild your character. This allows you to reassign your perks and skill points, delevels you to 1, and awards you an amount of experience equal to what was removed. Not all perks are stripped however, and thus you effectively double your perks.